# Probability of symmetric difference vanishes, then $P(\limsup A_n)=P(\liminf A_n)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $\left\{{A_n}\right\}_{n \in{} \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of events in a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$, such that $P(A \Delta A_n) \xrightarrow{ n \to \infty } 0$ where $A$ is equal to $\limsup_{ n \to \infty } A_n$ or equal to $\liminf_{ n \to \infty } A_n$, I want to prove that $P\left( \limsup_{ n \to \infty } A_n \setminus \liminf_{ n \to \infty } A_n \right)$=0. The result is intuitively clear, but I have not finished the proof. My idea of the proof is the following:

Let be $A^*:=\limsup_{ n \to \infty } A_n$ if $A=\liminf_{ n \to \infty } A_n$, and $A^*:=\liminf_{ n \to \infty } A_n$ if $A=\limsup_{ n \to \infty } A_n$. Then $P\left( \limsup_{ n \to \infty } A_n \setminus \liminf_{ n \to \infty } A_n \right)=P(A \Delta A^*)\leq P(A_n \Delta A^*)+P(A \Delta A_n)$ for all $n$, so we can conclude if we show that $P(A_n \Delta A^*) \xrightarrow{ n \to \infty } 0$, but I could not prove this last part.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, as an example, a probability space supporting a sequence $(X_n)$ of independent Bernoulli random variables with $P[X_n=1]=1/n$. Set $A_n=\{X_n=1\}$. Then $P(\liminf_nA_n)=0$ and $\lim_nP(A_n)=0$, so taking $A:=\liminf_nA_n$ you have $\lim_nP(A\Delta A_n)=0$. But $P(\limsup_nA_n)=1$ by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: Thank you by your help! I was thinking that this was a true affirmation.